# Submitting iOS App to App Store for Review Without Pushing Server Updates to Production

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Our platform is undergoing a major upgrade that amongst other things impact's the database schema and data relationships.

We have updated our apps and are about to submit them to the App Store for approval. We will be submitting the app with the API endpoints pointing to our production environment but the new endpoints will only work once the DB schema of our platform is upgraded which we do not want to do till our app is approved.

Does anyone have an approach on how to proceed? Is there a way to provision the app with staging and production API endpoints, have Apple review on staging endpoints but make the app live with production endpoints?

PS - Due to timing constraints we have not worked on our platform upgrade with backward compatibility so we would be asking our iOS app users to upgrade to the new app once our platform is successfully upgraded.

Comment: probably submit with a older end point, get it approved. change a bool of production server to YES to have everything as you wanted for release.

Comment: Does your old live app version still work on the old platform?

Comment: @Shubhank can't do this as the new app won't work with the old data model and the old app won't work with the new one

Comment: @hasan83 yes. In other words, current app works with current platform. Future platform won't work with current app and future app won't work with current platform.

Comment: I believe you have no solution for this. apple needs to test your app will not allow a not working one.

Comment: I contacted Apple someday for something a bit similar : we could not create production account for them (government app). They told us we could provided a download link to an app in sandbox in the iTunes Connect review information. We found a workaround filtering on IP (the app was dedicated to french marked) to redirect Apple to another server so never actually tried this.

Comment: @NicolasBraun I did have to end up making adjustments to our infrastructure along with the use of subdomains to workaround this handicap. Currently we have endpoints like this www.xyz.com/api/do/this. I've created a public test server with the subdomain (api.xyz.com/api/do/this) that will point to that server during review and to our production server once the app has been approved.

Comment: Yeah already did that trick but keep in mind that your updates will have to be reviewed by Apple to and will not want to redirect everyone to your test environment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an idea may work for you. Put your new platform in a temporary server. let your app. connect to it only for apple testing. give apple a test user that only connects to the temporary server and all others connects to the live server.

later you can upload a new version that does not include that logic. a x.x.1 version.

remember to select the option saying developer release. means that your app will be accepted but will not get released until you release it manually. this allows you to release the app. and update your platform synchronously.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I've done something along the lines to what you have suggested.

Comment: one more thing after you release your app manually it may take several houes for store processing. so wait until that gets done with then update your server.